# Location based self serve ad servers?

Tags: advertising

I'm looking for recommendations for a location based ad server for my website, like Adsense, but geo-targeted.

Ideally, I'd like it to be self serve, so I can choose what ads are displayed where, with advertisers coming directly to me rather than the server...

Any recommendations?

Ta

Comment: FYI, AdSense _is_ geo-targetted. It's just that the advertisers decide which geographic demographic they want their ads to appear in.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openx.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenX](http://www.openx.org/publisher/open-source-ad-server) has a [geographic targeting](http://www.openx.org/support/geotargeting) option starting from $50+$12/month for updates (also note that OpenX is open-source and free).
Fairly easy learning curve (though administartion can be improved) and lots, lots of options.

The script began as a fork of phpAds, and went through the names phpAdsNew, OpenAds and finally OpenX if that rings a bell.

Comment: Thanks; what is the $50 figure for as can't seem to see any prices on their website?! Cheers

Comment: It is for the geotargeting option only. Use ctrl+f -> Geographic databases on the second link.